# c-set-style: Error loading guessed style

Tags: c, style

My company has very specific indentation rules for C code. I want to create a style from those rules, and have it load at startup.

Doing a C/Guess Style From This Buffer and C/Install Last Guessed Style works great. It indents properly. But it goes away when I exit Emacs, and I have to guess and install the style again.

So I a did a C/View Last Guessed Style. I get a buffer with a very long lisp expression (78 lines) starting with

```
(c-add-style "STYLE NAME HERE"
             '("style-name-I-installed-interactively"
               (c-basic-offset . 3)     ; Guessed value
               (c-offsets-alist
                (arglist-cont . 0)      ; Guessed value
                (arglist-intro . ++)    ; Guessed value
```

I was a little confused why it asked me to enter a style name when I already did, and it listed it in the lisp (as I show above), but I changed the style name to what I wanted, which was identical to `style-name-I-installed-interactively`.

When I evaluate this buffer, everything is fine, but when I go to set the style (`C-c .`), I see

```
c-get-style-variables: Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While composing this and doing my due diligence, I solved my problem. For some reason, Emacs generated the expression with the name I chose to name the style as the *base style*, and because I specified the same name for both the base style and the added style name, it got into an infinite recursion loop in `c-get-style-variables` when it tried to evaluate things. (I figured this out by doing `M-: (debug (c-set-style "style-name-I-installed-interactively"))` and looking at the backtrace.) Removing the second `"style-name-I-installed-interactively"`, which turns out to be optional, solved my problem.

So for people who see `c-get-style-variables: Variable binding depth exceeds max-specpdl-size`, elisp stack overflow is one potential cause.